# How to align item in react native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to align my logo (the grey K) on the middle. i put my justify content and my align items to center the K but it doesn't work. I might do something wrong with my view ?

It's for IOS

```
<View style={{flex: 1, marginBottom: 50}}>
            <View style={{marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10}}>
              {this.renderMonDashboardOpenDb()}
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 1, marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
             
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 30,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                  color: 'white',
                 
                }}>
                Klaaap pour défendre tes couleurs !
              </Text>
              </View>
              
             
              <View style={{flex: 1,  alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Decibels')}><Image style={styles.logoVert} source={require('./Kvert.png')} /></TouchableOpacity>
              
           
              </View>
[...]
</View>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the width of the surrounding View is not 100%?
To figure out you can set the color of the View which is surrounds the TouchableOpacity to red and now you can see if its width is over the whole screen.
If its not, you just have to set the width to 100% and everything will get centered.

Hope this helps maybe!
Good Luck.